# describe the meaning of the shorthand notation of .net?("+=","=>")

Tags: c#, .net

The first one  code is shorthand notation of second:

```
itemCountLines.Click = itemCountLines.Click + (sender, args) => countLines();


itemCountLines.Click += (sender, args) => CountLines();
```

But i did not understand what this expression is doing.Anybody Please Explain it to me

Comment: lookup  anonymous methods and lambda expressions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code adds an handler to the [`Control.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
public event EventHandler Click
```

where `EventHandler` is a delegate of type:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(
    object sender,
    EventArgs e
)
```

Normally, given you have a method with the same signature:

```
void SomeClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CountLines(); 
}
```

you would add this handler to handle `Click` event:

```
itemCountLines.Click += SomeClickHandler;
```

Operator `+=` is possible because `Click` is an `event`, so you can add or remove a multiple `EventHandler`s to it. Simple speaking, after some control is clicked, you may want to make multiple actions (show some other control, log it to the database etc) so you are able to add multiple event handlers. You can even do `itemCountLines.Click -= SomeClickHandler` somewhere later to say, you do not want to handle `Click` with `SomeClickHandler` anymore.

But above code needs to define method `SomeClickHandler` which sometimes is unnecessary (for example, it is used only one in whole class). Then you can use *anonymous delegate* (added in C# 2.0):

```
itemCountLines.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)   
                  {   
                    CountLines(); 
                  };
```

but you can further shorten this syntax with *lambda expression* (added in C# 3.0) to:

```
itemCountLines.Click += (sender, args) => CountLines();
```

Comment: what is "+=" mean? we adding someclickhandler to itemcountlines.click.That does not make sense

Comment: It makes perfect sense. `Click` is `event` which makes is possible to add and remove `EventHandler`s to it.

Comment: so we adding this handler (sender, args) to click event to know sender and argumnets then call a countLines function right?

Comment: thanks man Just last question.This article i reading http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus. look for function name CountLines().The value he is using like 'SelectedItemPaths' are came through the (sender or arg)?

Comment: @user3187056, I believe it comes from base class `SharpContextMenu`. Event handler, even anonymous, have access to the fields of the class that is being declared.

Comment: there have a function CountLines() with no parameters.what do you think 'SelectedItemPaths' is global var.because i am mostly familiar with c++. thats why i am having problem to understand

Comment: @user3187056, it is not a global variable, but field of class. There is concept of objects and fields in C++ so you are similar with it probably.

Answer (score 0):

It simply add an event to  the list of listeners `itemCountLines.Click = itemCountLines.Click + (sender, args)`  so  when an event occurs the instance of sender will  be notified  to raise the event  inline `=> countLines();` as you are using lambda Expression `=>` which will  invoke `countLines` method

Answer (score 0):

You're just attaching an event on `Click`, it is the same as saying

```
itemCountLines.Click += CountLines(sender, args);
```

Somewhere, there should be a method like this :

```
private void CountLines()
{
    // Some Code There
}
```